# Is it possible to max 2 skill trees?

Tags: borderlands-2

To start off, I AM TERRIBLE WITH MATHS!

However, I play as a gunzerker and I would like to know if it is possible to max out 2 skill trees.

If not, how many more points would I need?

Comment: by max out two skill trees, I assume you mean obtain two final tier skills? At this time, no.

Comment: You can get a point in the bottom skill of one tree, and the middle skill of a second, but that's the best you can do until expansions are released.

Comment: what agent86 said. hopefully the next DLC will up the level cap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, if you have the [Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1022/borderlands-2-level-increase-and-other-changes), which increases the level cap to 61. For example, see this [Salvador/Gunzerker build which maxes out two skill trees at just level 57](http://www.bl2skills.com/gunzerker.html#000000000005005015315105050050551):

[image: Salvador/Gunzerker build which maxes out two skill trees at just level 57]

Comment: Uh, you have to buy a DLC to get the additional levels right?

Comment: @Meraj99 You need the [Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1022/borderlands-2-level-increase-and-other-changes) to get to Level 61. (More info in the link.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think (for now) you can.

You get 46 skill points at maximum level (50), and if you head over their [character planner](http://www.borderlands2.com/us/skilltree/gunzerker.html) you see this:

- 1 skill point is "wasted" for your gunzerking ability
- fill out the first skill tree -> you will need at least 26 skill points
- this leaves 19 more points --> you will need 7 more points to have another tree filled completely

In [early 2k13](https://twitter.com/PezRadar/status/281750585261322240) level cap will rise. In the first Borderlands, after the expansion, you could. So maybe in this chapter it will be possible too

Comment: The max level in the original Borderlands gave you 57 skill points, which actually made it possible to put at least 1 point in each final skill.  I wouldn't be surprised if they added at least 7 more.

Comment: Will update my answer with your information :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot max out two skill trees as of now.  At max level (50) you have 46 skill points.  You would need 7 more skill points to reach the last tier skill of another branch.  At this time, it is unknown what the level cap will be raised to, but there is an intended level cap increase which could make this possible in the near future.

Note that skill bonuses from class mods do not count towards unlocking the next tier of a branch.

The borderlands 2 website has interactive skill trees if you want to plan out your build: http://www.borderlands2.com/us/skilltree/

Answer (score 0):

Well the recent level cap was 50 but now it is 61 so, yes you can fill both and instead of 46 skill points 57 will be your new final result but "boosting" or getting a constant 307 experience per second will take you 40 minutes from level 50 to 61.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to purchase the DLC in order to be able to max out two branches. Just like the other people had said. The DLC isn't too expensive either. If you are playing on Xbox, on the marketplace, it's only ten dollars. That goes for all of the DLCs.